# Map NullPointerException in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a class for Vehicle and what I'm trying to do is link a bunch of VehicleParts to this Vehicle. Obviously, a normal vehicle can't have two engines, so what I'm thinking of storing them in is a map, more specifically an EnumMap

```
public enum VehiclePartType {
  ENGINE_BLOCK,
  CRANKSHAFT,
  //..etc
}

public class VehiclePart {
  public String name;
  public VehiclePartType partType;
  //some more basic variables + ModelFinder
}

public class Vehicle {

  //some basic string variables and a ModelFinder

@ManyToMany
public Map<VehiclePartType, VehiclePart> parts = 
  new EnumMap<VehiclePartType, VehiclePart>(VehiclePartType.class);

}
```

Usage: When i try to associate a part with a given vehicle.

```
Vehicle vehicle = Vehicle.finderVehicle.byId(id);
VehiclePart vehiclePart = VehiclePart.finderVehiclePart.byId(partId);
vehicle.parts.put(VehiclePartType.ENGINE_BLOCK, vehiclePart);
vehicle.saveManyToManyAssociations("parts");
```

This creates the table I want in the SQL database and stores the proper reference IDs, but whenever I try to access it via Java code, such as the following code, I get an error:

```
Vehicle.allVehicles();

[RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)
(through reference chain: com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[1]->models.Vehicle["parts"])]
```

If I change the map to a list, this works fine, but that's not what I'm going for since I won't be able to get a part by its VehiclePartType without searching through the entire list of parts.

First, is this an acceptable way of storing the VehicleParts?
Second, I'm not sure how to resolve this null error.  Any help with this would be appreciated.